# how to install the signal handler for an arbitrary process with a known pid

Tags: signals, embedded-linux

I have a following problem (Linux):

1. we have a 3rd party software which has GUI and can process the keyboard input
   I will refer to it as a parent, it looks like it filters out everything which is not its own
   hotkey (alias to its internal commands, let's say pressing CTRL-D causes some parent command
   processing)
2. the parent invokes my software (child) which is passed as an argument on the command line
3. the child need to react when user presses some hotkey in the parent GUI

My initial hope was to have a keylogger and monitor the /proc device input, but all this thing is running on the VM and everything in /proc device input is privileged and not accessible to me.
Another idea I have is maybe I can I install the signal handler "for the parent process" from the "child process" and within that handler use something like SIGUSR1 to inform the child?

Is it possible to install the signal handler from one process into another one?
Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another clumsy way is to have a wrapper around the "parent process". This wrapper can have a signal handler for the target hotkey. Now the "parent process" is invoked through the wrapper instead of being called directly and, if the wrapper invokes the "parent process" as its child, the "parent process" should inherit this signal handler and react to the target hotkey. To inform "parent's child", I might create a "signal file" and its existence can be periodically verified inside the "child process". Need to be careful here because the last signal handler for the "target hotkey" wins for the "parent" process